# Foliation vs Coordinates in de Sitter

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, general-relativity

I'm studying de Sitter manifolds and am confused about the difference between the choice of foliation and the choice of coordinates (and how they relate to the spatial curvature).  I can choose the natural coordinates with $K = 1$, and this makes the spatial slices surfaces of 3-spheres.  On the other hand, I can choose conformally flat coordinates with $K = 0$ and I assume the spatial slices are sheets here.  Still, in both cases the metric has the form (neglecting the pre-factor)

$$ds^2 = -d\eta^2+d\Sigma^2$$

and I can choose either

$$d\Sigma^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$

or

$$d\Sigma^2 = dr^2 + r^2d\Omega_2^2$$

which I visualize as sheets and balls respectively.  I understand de Sitter is a special case due to its many symmetries, but this is confusing me about the difference between the spatial curvature ($K$), the foliation, and the labeling (i.e. coordinates).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: As this question has been sitting around for a couple days, you might want to [edit] it to include as much basic information about de Sitter manifolds (including basic definitions) as possible to make it possible for readers without specific knowledge of these objects to provide an answer (or at least make sense of the question). If you still don't get any responses within a week or so, you might want to raise a flag for moderators to migrate this question to [mathoverflow.se]. (This question is certainly well outside my own wheel-house.)